# Allow user to destroy post only if they created it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I currently have a simple and effective authorization setup as shown below.

Currently, admin users (and noone else) can destroy posts. However, I would also like to allow users to be able to destroy ***their own*** post.

How can I achieve this?

user.rb

```rb
def editor? 
  self.role == 'editor' 
end

def admin? 
  self.role == 'admin'
end
```

application controller

```rb
   helper_method :current_user

   def current_user
     @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
   end 

   def require_user
     redirect_to '/login' unless current_user
   end 

   def require_editor 
     redirect_to '/' unless current_user.editor? 
   end

   def require_admin
     redirect_to '/' unless current_user.admin? 
   end
```

posts controller

```rb
  before_action :require_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :require_editor, only: [:edit]
  before_action :require_admin, only: [:destroy]
```

in the view

```rb
<% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>
# Destroy button
<% end %>
```

Comment: Check if `post.author_id == user_id`? What the problem?

Comment: @Зелёный I could hack something together but I want to go with best practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption: Your Post has a `user_id`.

```
<% if current_user&.admin? || post.user_id == current_user.id %>
```

`current_user&.admin?` is short for `current_user && current_user.admin?` and then you check if the post is created by the current user.

Also rewrite before action:

```
before_action :require_admin_or_owner, only: [:destroy]

def require_admin_or_owner
  redirect_to '/' unless current_user.admin? || 
    Post.find(params[:id]).user_id == current_user.id
end
```

Comment: Thank you this is helpful. I think you mean `||` (in place of `&&`)? In any case, I tried both and they don't work - should I change other code too? (in case it helps, I simply get redirected to the home page and the server says `Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_admin rendered or redirected`

Comment: Do I need to somehow override `before_action :require_admin, only: [:destroy]` ? (since the user who made the post is not an admin)

Comment: Ohh I missread some sentence in your question. It should be `||` and you have to remove or rewrite `require_admin`. Since two before actions get called on `:destroy` and the admin check will fail obviously. Something like `def require_admin_or_owner;  redirect_to '/' unless current_user.admin? || Post.find(params[:id]).user_id == current_user.id; end`

Comment: does that mean I should replace the line `before_action :require_admin, only: [:destroy]` with the four lines `def require_admin_or_owner
  redirect_to '/' unless current_user.admin? || 
    Post.find(params[:id]).user_id == current_user.id
end` ?

Comment: Made an edit to the answer, hopefully this is more explanatory.